# Dynamic form with composable-form

Tags: elm

I'm trying to implement a dynamic form in Elm 0.19 using [hecrj/composable-form](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/hecrj/composable-form/8.0.1/).

I receive a json with the fields, their descriptions, etc, so I don't know beforehand how many fields it will have.

So the traditional way of defining a form:

```
Form.succeed OutputValues
      |> Form.append field1
      |> Form.append field2
```

doesn't work because I don't know the `OutputValues` structure beforehand.

I've seen there is a function `Form.list` which looks like a promising path, though it seems to expect all fields equal, which is not my case, I may have a text field and a select field for example.

Is there any straight forward way of doing this with this library?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form library doesn't explicitly support what you're trying to do, but we can make it work!

#### tldr;

Here's my example of how you can take JSON and create a form: https://ellie-app.com/bJqNh29qnsva1

#### How to get there

`Form.list` is definitely the promising path. You're also exactly right that `Form.list` requires all of the fields to be of the same type. So let's start there! We can make one data structure that can hold them by making a custom type. In my example, I called it `DynamicFormFieldValue`. We'll make a variant for each kind of field. I created ones for text, integer, and select list. Each one will need to hold the value of the field and all of the extras (like title and default value) to make it show up nicely. This will be what we decode the JSON into, what the form value is, and what the form output will be. The resulting types looks like this:

```
type alias TextFieldRequirements =
    { name : String
    , default : Maybe String
    }


type alias IntFieldRequirements =
    { name : String
    , default : Maybe Int
    }


type alias SelectFieldRequirements =
    { name : String
    , default : Maybe String
    , options : List ( String, String )
    }


type DynamicFormFieldValue
    = TextField String TextFieldRequirements
    | IntField Int IntFieldRequirements
    | SelectField String SelectFieldRequirements
```

To display the form, you just need a function that can take the form value and display the appropriate form widget. The form library provides `Form.meta` to change the form based on the value. So, we will pattern match on the custom type and return `Form.textField`, `Form.numberField`, or `Form.selectField`. Something like this:

```
dynamicFormField : Int -> Form DynamicFormFieldValue DynamicFormFieldValue
dynamicFormField fieldPosition =
    Form.meta
        (\field ->
            case field of
                TextField textValue ({ name } as requirements) ->
                    Form.textField
                        { parser = \_ -> Ok field
                        , value = \_ -> textValue
                        , update = \value oldValue -> TextField value requirements
                        , error = always Nothing
                        , attributes =
                            { label = name
                            , placeholder = ""
                            }
                        }

                IntField intValue ({ name } as requirements) ->
                    Form.numberField
                        { parser = \_ -> Ok field
                        , value = \_ -> String.fromInt intValue
                        , update = \value oldValue -> IntField (Maybe.withDefault intValue (String.toInt value)) requirements
                        , error = always Nothing
                        , attributes =
                            { label = name
                            , placeholder = ""
                            , step = Nothing
                            , min = Nothing
                            , max = Nothing
                            }
                        }

                SelectField selectValue ({ name, options } as requirements) ->
                    Form.selectField
                        { parser = \_ -> Ok field
                        , value = \_ -> selectValue
                        , update = \value oldValue -> SelectField value requirements
                        , error = always Nothing
                        , attributes =
                            { label = name
                            , placeholder = ""
                            , options = options
                            }
                        }
        )
```

Hooking this display function up is a bit awkward with the library. `Form.list` wasn't designed with use-case in mind. We want the list to stay the same length and just be iterated over. To achieve this, we will remove the "add" and "delete" buttons and be forced to provide a dummy default value (which will never get used).

```
dynamicForm : Form (List DynamicFormFieldValue) (List DynamicFormFieldValue)
dynamicForm =
    Form.list
        { default =
            -- This will never get used
            TextField "" { name = "", default = Nothing }
        , value = \value -> value
        , update = \value oldValue -> value
        , attributes =
            { label = "Dynamic Field Example"
            , add = Nothing
            , delete = Nothing
            }
        }
        dynamicFormField
```

Hopefully the ellie example demonstrates the rest and you can adapt it to your needs!

Comment: In addition, if some fields are required or not can be also be handled as shown here: https://ellie-app.com/bMvRDyhLDF8a1